# google admob ad doesn't pop up

Tags: android, admob

My problem is when I try ads in test mode as it is mentioned in google website for developers ads pop up, but when I get my app id and adUnitId and try to integrate real ads - ads don't pop up. The app was published approximately 7 days ago (12.07.2017). Ads should appear when user presses cover art image of a song - new fragment appears and at the bottom there should be BANNER ad.
The link of the App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=skyplayer.ivanets.a1.musicplayerwithads&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is when I try ads in test mode as it is mentioned in google website for developers ads pop up

Test Ads appearing means your **code is fine**.

> but when I get my app id and adUnitId and try to integrate real ads - ads don't pop up.

Make sure you have added **correct** APP ID and AdUnit ID given in admob console otherwise ads won't load. **Note** that ads only loads if its available . It's not necessary that ads loads everytime .

> You can use AdListener and monitor why it is not showing ads . Remember if you have created fresh ad units then it will take some time or few hours to arrange live ads for it . If test ads are showing and you have valid ad unit id and also your app has not violated any policy then you are good to go (You will be emailed if your app have a policy issue) . Ads will be shown when availabe.

[See this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45152466/8321236)

Comment: happy to help :)